# Can't get bootstrap's media layout to align image against a centered heading

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align an image to the left of a heading, using bootstraps media layout. What is happening is that the image is aligning to the left of the browser while the heading is centered. I've tried a number of different things, but this is the code that I believe "should" be correct:

```
<div>
    <!-- some stuff -->
    <div class="text-center form-inline">
        <div class="media">
            <div class="media-left" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <div class="visible-lg">
                    <img data-bind="attr.src: agencyLogo" width="200" height="100"></img>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="media-body" style="vertical-align: middle">
                <h1 class="media-heading">My Cool Header</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- some more stuff -->
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

From the bootstrap documentation:

```
<div class="media">
    <a class="media-left" href="#">
        <img class="media-object" data-src="holder.js/64x64" alt="Generic placeholder image">
    </a>
    <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
        Cras sit amet nibh libero,....
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is happening is that the image is aligning to the left of the browser while the heading is centered.

The reason this is happening is because you have two `div` elements, which by default have the [`display`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) value `block`.

If you would like the two elements to not be block elements, and "align" next to each other you have to either use a different `display` property (such as `inline` or `flex`) or give the elements a [`float` property + value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp).

Check below for examples or [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq626nwk/1/);

```css
.el1, .el3, .el5 {
    background-color: grey;
}

.el2, .el4 {
    background-color: lightblue;
}

.el1 {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.el2, .el3 {
    display: inline;
}

.el4, .el5 {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.flexin {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.el6, .el7 {
    background-color: orange;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-flex: 1; 
    -ms-flex: 1;   
    flex: 1;
}

/* micro cf */
cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="el1">I have display block</div>
<div class="el2">I have display inline</div>
<div class="el3">I also have display inline</div>
<div class='cf'>
    <div class="el4">My float value is left</div>
    <div class="el5">My float value is also left</div>
</div>
<div class='flexin'>
    <div class="el6">My parent's display value is flex</div>
    <div class="el7">And our flex value is 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to do this using the bootstrap's media layout. I understand that divs are block elements, but even if I wrap the img tag with a span, it still doesn't work. See the edit above from bootstrap's docs.

Comment: @MusicalShore - I don't know what a 'media layout' is, please provide links and [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it will be easy to help